# Error: Duplicate headers received from server

Tags: php

Dublicate error happened in chrome, opera, safari and only works on firefox.
Here's the header:

```
| Header
    | Forcing a download using readfile()
    |----------------
    */

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $file_mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $file_size);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
```

I've tried to put double quotes and works but adds to file name - for e.g. -'filename.pdf'

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= . '$file'");
```

Comment: You can't have 2 `header('Content-Description: ...` at same time

Comment: What you mean ? to remove first line - header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix issue you need

```
// Change this 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file);

// To this 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
```

Comment: Awesome now works on all browsers.Actually it's this script http://www.tutorialchip.com/php-download-file-script/ I think it's old and for thus have a problem.

Comment: How is `Content-Description` the same header as `Content-Disposition`?

Comment: Ups :) my bad @Barmar, ok his problem was just with quotas, updating answer

Comment: @Armen With first line as you said to remove works and without works.Is this a problem to keep first or to remove ?

Comment: Tangentially related: if your filename contains special characters, various browsers will need special handling: http://stackoverflow.com/q/93551/1233508

Comment: @amarullzamarullzz no you can keep it, you just need to fix  `Content-Disposition` like in updated answer